# Authentication OneDrive Python API

Tags: python-3.x, sdk, oauth-2.0, onedrive

I am trying to use my OneDrive for business with Python.

I have installed onedrivesdk and now I am in the process of authenticating my OneDrive

the code provided is the following

```
import onedrivesdk

redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080/'
client_secret = 'your_client_secret'
client_id='your_client_id'
api_base_url='https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/'
scopes=['wl.signin', 'wl.offline_access', 'onedrive.readwrite']

http_provider = onedrivesdk.HttpProvider()
auth_provider = onedrivesdk.AuthProvider(
http_provider=http_provider,
client_id=client_id,
scopes=scopes)

client = onedrivesdk.OneDriveClient(api_base_url, auth_provider, http_provider)
auth_url = client.auth_provider.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)
```

I am not sure what is the client_secret and client_id I should provide to get access to my OneDrive

I will appreciate help regarding from where to get the above mentioned parameters.

Comment: Did you get it?

Answer (score 5):

The `client_secret` and `client_id` are two required parameters needed to use [OAuth2](https://oauth.net/2/), which is an industry-standard protocol for authorization.

Take a look at these following links to know how to get these information related to OneDrive access:

https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm

[Get Access Token with OneDrive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38899806/get-access-token-with-onedrive-api)

You will need to register your application following this link:
https://dev.onedrive.com/app-registration.htm

After that, your application will receive some request and, with valid user credentials, get access to OneDrive account.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have registered the app so now I have a client_id as well as password. But how now I relate/ link my OneDrive to the app I have registered with Microsoft?, Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: Now you have to get a valid token for your user. The token flow is also explained at the link I informed. You need to understand the OAuth2 flow.